# How to exclude hair particles from freestyle render?

Tags: rendering, particles, blender-internal-render-engine, freestyle

Is there a way to prevent freestyle from rendering lines on hair particles?

I still want to render lines on the mesh which has the particle system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use compositing. Enable strand render for the hair. Create one render layer with Freestyle enabled and Strand disabled. A second layer with Solid and Freestyle disabled and Strand enabled. That will give you one layer with freestyle lines around the object and another with just hair.

[image]

Composite together with an alpha over.

[image]